# Running a script stored as jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I want to be able to run scripts grabbed from one place, in another. I have access to these scripts using the following jQuery:

```
element.each(function(){
    var script = $(this).find('script');
    // I want to run contained scripts here.
});
```

I am just unsure how to use these objects to run the scripts they contain (are).

An example of an inline script I have to re-run (from a third party)

```
<script language="javascript">
    interact.embedApp({
    target: "bame", width: 1, height: 1,
    vars: {id: "1", resolveJSPath:"true"},
    params: {allowScriptAccess: "always",base:"http://",deepLinking:"false",wmode: "transparent"},
    src: [
        {type:"html5", src:"http://", xd: ["http://"]},
        {type:"swf", src:"http://",version:"0"}
    ]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you have inserted the `<script>` into the DOM it has _already_ been run.

Comment: Alnitak yes indeed, I need to re-run them.

Comment: in which case just put all the code in (named) functions and _reinvoke those functions!_

Comment: @Alnitak how do I convert the inline functions to named ones?

Comment: chances are they already have names - please show some (abbreviated) sample scripts, and also their `<script>` tags.

Comment: @Alnitak I edited the question to provide the inline script example.

Comment: ok, if it's third party script that you can't modify that's not so straightforward.  It still begs the question of _why_ you apparently need to re-run it.

Comment: It is dirty, but these third party scripts require external JS which gets loaded when they are detected.

Comment: doh!  If it's inline then _of course_ you can modify it!  Just wrap the whole thing with `function embed() { ... }` and then call `embed()` any time you want it to execute.

Comment: (the caveat about modifying third party scripts only really applies to ones loaded externally with a `src` attribute.  Anything you're copying and pasting into your own HTML is fair game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be including *inline* script content, albeit content that has been provided by a third party.

In this instance you can wrap the body of the code that they have supplied in your own function:

```
<script>
var invoke = invoke || [];    // make sure the array exists

invoke.push([function() {
    // third party code goes here
}, [arg1, arg2]]);             // optional arguments
</script>
```

and then any time after that (including the first time!) when you want to call all the functions:

```
function invokeAll() {
    return invoke.map(function(a) {
        var f = a[0];
        var args = a.slice(1);
        var ctx = a[2];
        return f.apply(ctx, args);
    });
}
```

Comment: This could work, it sucks a bit because it means people adding this manually (it will be in a CMS). However my question is, how would I invoke this embed() inside a .each()?

Comment: well, you could collect a global array of the above such functions into which you add them as they're loaded, and then just iterate over that array of functions...

Comment: @theorise and updated further, for increased flexibility

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Blob` object (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob)). Here's a function using it:

```
function getInlineJS(elem) {
        var js = elem.textContent;
        var blob = new Blob([js], {"type": "application\/javascript"});
        return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}
```

This [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/nngqLcrg/) uses it to create a web worker

Like @Alnitak remarked, this can only be applied to inline script tags. If the originating `scr` server has enabled [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) it should be possible to retrieve scripting source code using XHR e.g. something like:

```
$.ajax( {
  url: [the src url]
 ,method: 'get'
 ,success: function(data) { /* ... */ }
} );
```

Comment: NB: AFAIK this will online work for inline script tags - scripts loaded from a remote server with the `src` attribute have no `.textContent`

Comment: Yep, that's a restriction. You will need the actual script source text